# Struct type pointers

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I am developing a [simple GUI application](https://github.com/golergka/FileHash) to compute the hash sums of files. It uses CommonCrypto library for hash sum algorythms. Therefore, the code that I use to compute [SHA1](https://github.com/golergka/FileHash/blob/develop/SHSHA1Computer.m) or [MD5](https://github.com/golergka/FileHash/blob/develop/SHMD5Computer.m) hashes, for example, is exactly the same, with the exception of elements that I use from the said library: constants, functions and structs. Of course, I can write more generic code that accepts constants as values & function pointers, but what do I do with the custom structs that are different for each type of hash?

For example, when I compute MD5 hash, I have this:

```
CC_MD5_CTX md5;
CC_MD5_Init(&md5);
```

And when I compute SHA1 hash, I have this:

```
CC_SHA1_CTX sha1;
CC_SHA1_Init(&sha1);
```

How can I convert it to one piece of code that just takes CC_HASH_CTX as a parameter?

P.S.: Although the application is written in Objective C for Mac, I presume that this question in particular is not specific to it, so I just tagged it with C.

Comment: You can't.  How would it know which algorithm to use?  You'll need at least one more parameter to specify that.

Comment: Well, of course I would also pass the function pointers with it. But that part seems simple enough.

Comment: You question says "that just takes CC_HASH_CTX as a parameter".  But if you can add parameters, just add one that says which algorithm to use.  Using a function pointer would work just fine.  I can't really see why you'd bother, though.  If you know which function pointer to send, you know which function you needed to call anyway.

Comment: I'm creating a separate class for each algorithm; I imagined that I could write the code in the abstract class and in the subclasses just provide the pointers to functions and constants needed in this particular algorithm.

Comment: Sure, you could do that.  What's the sticking point?

Comment: Well, I don't understand how to store and use a pointer to a particular type of a struct.

Comment: You can use `void *` to store an arbitrary pointer.

Comment: I'm still being a bit stupid about it. If you could provide a code example of what you mean, it would be extremely nice.

Comment: Well hopefully someone will get here soon - I'm using my iPad, so typing accurate code is a giant pain.  If I get to a computer I'll definitely I do that.